# TCP Socket Listener clients disconnected when Application Pool recycled

Tags: c#, sockets, iis, asp.net-web-api, tcpclient

I created a TCP socket listener wherein multiple clients are connecting. This listener class is included on a WEB Api which is deployed on the Internet Information Services (IIS). My problem is every time the application pool is recycled, all clients were disconnected. Is there any way to retain connected clients upon app pool recycling? I tried to use Singleton pattern but it seems it still re-instantiate the listener class after recycling.

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: Hi drum. I used this MSDN example as reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: I found this https://serverfault.com/questions/222385/what-does-recycling-the-app-pool-actually-do-exactly

Comment: This is the opposite of my problem. On his case the problem get solved every time the app pool is recycled, on my side the problem persist when the app pool is recycled. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to participate in the application pool, why have you built your TCP server inside of an application that is hosted inside the application pool? Create a separate windows service for the TCP side of things rather than putting it inside an asp.net application.

Comment: Actually It was on windows service before but when the project requires a web API part, I thought it will minimize the part of deployment if I'll just include it in the API. If I cant find any solution to this I might roll it back to windows service. Thanks for the response Damien!